# Triangle inequality for cheapest simple paths

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E,I,W)$ is a *directed graph*, where $V$ is the set of vertices, $E$ is the set of edges, $I: E \rightarrow V^2$ is an incidence function, and $W: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a weight function.

A *simple path* of length $L$ from $v_1 \in V$ to $v_{L+1} \in V$ through $v_2, v_3, \ldots, v_L \in V$
is a subset of $E$ with edges $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_L \in E$, where $I(e_i)=(v_i,v_{i+1})$,
$e_i \ne e_j$, and $v_k \ne v_l$ for all  $1 \le i,j \le L$ with $k \ne l$ and $1 \le k,l \le L+1$
with $k \ne l$.
$P=\{e_1,e_2,...,e_L\}$ is a *cheapest simple path* from $v_1$ to $v_{L+1}$ if
$c(P)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^L W(e_i)$ is minimal, where $c(P)$ is the *cost* of $P$.

The *simple cycle* $C=\{e_1,e_2,...,e_{L+1}\}$ is the union of $P$ and $e_{L+1}$
with incidence $I(e_{L+1})=(v_{L+1},v_1)$.
The *cost* of cycle $C$ is defined as $c(C)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{L+1} W(e_i)$.

Here **only** simple paths and simple cycles are considered.

My question is how to prove the following lemma for a graph $G$ without negative-cost simple cycles:

> If $Q$ and $R$ are cheapest simple paths from $s \in V$ to $u \in V$
> and from $s \in V$ to $v \in V$, respectively, and $\epsilon \in E$
> with incidence $I(\epsilon)=(u,v)$, then $c(Q) + W(\epsilon) \ge c(R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases. If $Q$ does not pass through $v$, then the edge set $Q'$, consisting of the edges of $Q$ followed by $\epsilon$ is a simple path from $s$ to $v$, so by the assumption that $R$ is a cheapest $s-v$ path we have $c(Q) + W(\epsilon) = c(Q') \geq c(R)$.

On the other hand, if $Q$ does pass through $v$, then $Q'$ is made up of a simple $s-v$ path $P$, followed by a simple cycle $C$. Then $$c(Q) + W(\epsilon) = c(Q') = c(P) + c(C) \geq c(R) + 0 = c(R).$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this proof! Then does it also mean that for a (strongly) connected $G$ graph (without negative-cost cycles), the cost of the $s \rightarrow v$ cheapest simple path, $c(s,v)$ for a fixed $s \in V$ and any $v \in V$ define a $\pi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ feasible potential with values $\pi(v)=c(s,v)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly! And if the digraph is not strongly connected, you can add a new vertex $s$ and zero-cost edges $sv$ for all $v \in V$. The function $\pi(v) = c(s,v)$ will be a feasible potential in this case as well (provided that there are no negative-cost cycles).

Comment: Thanks again. I think that this is a very transparent proof for the existence of a feasible potential. Books always use shortest paths (more precisely, walks) and the Bellman-Ford algorithm to find feasible potentials, but I think that (in principle) there is no need for it, because cheapest simple paths always exist, but of course, their costs satisfy the triangle inequality only in the absence of negative-cost cycles. In practice, when one ould like to find a feasible potential in polynomial time, then the Bellman-Ford procedure is a computationally effective way for it.